# Synchronize Computer Audio Devices

Tags: mac, sync, audio, connection

My friend and I  have two Macbook Pros, each with an LED Cinema Display being used for audio. When my friend listens to music I can't hear it as well as him, because I am in front of my own machine.

I would like to set things up so when his computer starts playing a sound, my speakers should start to output the sounds too, so that both computers are playing the same audio synchronized.  This way I could hear better.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it over the network with [Rogue Amoeba](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/)'s [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) product along with their free [Airfoil Speakers](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php) software.

Answer (score 1):

Get an audio cable splitter and split the output of his machine to go to both monitors.  This will mean you'll hear all of his sounds and none of yours.

You might also be able to take the output of his machine (via the splitter) and feed it in to the Line In input on your machine.  Then you could mix his audio in with yours and your audio plus his would come out of your speakers